# How did they create the hole in Robert Downey Jr.'s chest for the Iron Man movie?

Tags: film-techniques, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

Don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I'm wondering how they created the hole in Robert Downey Jr.'s chest so they can put the reactor there? Here is the video "Iron Man: Behind the Scenes" where you can see the actual hole; this is behind the scenes so no CG.

[image]

Comment: I don't know this for certain, but the way he's slouched in the chair and the way the skin sits, I always assumed that he had a sort of prosthetic chest and he was actually deeper in the chair than he appears to be.

Comment: @JohnO many film-makers prefer physical effects, even if it's for mainly emotional reasons, and on a film with a budget like Iron Man's this kind of stuff is a drop in an ocean. Also, I think you're overestimating how much it costs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This was done using a prosthetic chest on his real chest (make sure to sing that to the tune of "We Want A Rock" by They Might Be Giants).

Skip to 2 minutes in for an explanation.

But to sum up: RDJ is actually sitting *inside* the chair you see. The chest is a sculpted prosthetic laying above him.

Comment: That's an awesome video. Cheers.

Comment: You can see Downey sitting under the prosthetics at 2:13 in the video in the question.

Comment: As MichaelItzoe wrote - after the cut to the view from far you can see the real legs of Downey below the chair. https://youtu.be/CoMnHpg198I?t=2m11s

Answer (score 12):

you can see in this pic They first created a prosthetic chest over his real chest and spray tanned it to match his original skin tone. Then they put in his "heart" so it would look like it's actually a hole in his chest while his actual chest is underneath it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, they showed it on youtube. They first created a prosthetic chest over his real chest and spray tanned it to match his original skin tone. Then they put in his "heart" so it would look like it's actually a hole in his chest while his actual chest is underneath it.

Comment: Welcome to [movies.se]. In which way does this answer provide more insights in addition to the already existing answer?